# Relation between $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I know that if $1\le p<q<\infty$ then $L^p\supset L^q $ and $l^p \supset l^q$.

But what is the relation between $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(\mathbb R)$?
I guess there is no relation, i.e. $L^1(\mathbb R) \subsetneq L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(\mathbb R) \subsetneq L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Can you give an example to show this?

Comment: The tags of your question seem to be a bit random.

Comment: You forgot to specify that the inclusion $L^p\supset L^q$ works when the space is *bounded*.

Comment: Didn´t You mean $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})\subset \ell^q(\mathbb{N})$ in the first line?

Comment: Which functions did you check before asking?

Comment: @b.ba sorry for getting on your nerves again. You should correct this in Your answer ...for $1\leq p \leq q$ one knows that $L^p(\Omega)\supset L^q(\Omega)$ if and only if $\Omega$ is bounded and $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})\subset \ell^q(\mathbb{N})$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f, g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{x} & \text{if $x > 1$}, \\
           0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & \text{if $0 < x < 1$}, \\
           0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $f \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$.